# Multiple conditions in if statement on non-contiguous cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I would like to perform an if statement with conditions on the values of multiple non-contiguous cells, something like

```
=IF(K2=O2=U2=AA2=AG2=AM2=AS2=AY2=BE2=BK2=BQ2=BW2=CC2=CI2=CO2=CU2=DA2=DG2=DM2=DS2=DY2=EE2=EK2=EN2=ER2=EV2=EZ2=FD2=0,"Pass","Fail")
```

However, this does not work. Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

I can't sum the cells because they contain positives and negatives and are potentially offsetting of each other, and I can't take the absolute values of the numbers in the array because the cells are non-contiguous.

I need specifically to check that each cell has value exactly zero in order to award a pass.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hidden row somewhere else on your sheet to do your calculations.

Hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select each cell you want to check. Right click and choose copy from the menu. Go to the row you want to use, click in the first cell, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then select the "paste links" button at the bottom of the window. This should show all the values side-by-side.

Now use an `IF` statement (like the one below) to check if all values are `0`. Note: where the `A20:B20` is, will need to be the range of the row you just created.

```
IF(SUM(A20:B20)=0, "Pass", "Fail")
```

Comment: Can you just confirm the Ctrl + N command as this creates a new workbook on my computer?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the answer with the correct key combination.

Comment: Great. If this works for you, feel free to choose it as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Zero is your friend and ally here.
If you sum up the absolute values, you will get something above Zero if a single one of your values is not zero. Negative ones will end up being positive because of the ABS function and thus not mess with your sum.
Like this:

```
=IF((ABS(K2)+ABS(O2)+....+ABS(CC2))=0,"Pass","Fail)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of doing this more concisely? E.g. applying `ABS` once to the entire range even though the cells are non-contiguous?

Comment: I doubt it. VBA might be the better approach there. Then you can simply have a list with cell references and loop through checking them for being zero.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that none of the other cells in row 2 have the value 0, and you have 28 cells to check, you can use

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(2:2, "=0")=28,"pass","fail")
```

This will ignore text in other fields in row 2, and if any of the numbers is non-zero or blank, it will give a fail.

If you have more or less than 28 values to check, then change this number accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As your range isn't contiguous at first you need to name it to refer to it easily: select all the cells in the range, than name it (guidance on named range is e.g. [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/2011-01-15-excel-range-name-overview.htm)).
Then there are a couple of functions you can use:

- `=IF(COUNTIF(yourRange,0)=COUNTA(yourRange),"pass","fail")`
- `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(yourRange,yourRange)=0,"pass","fail")`
- `=IF(SUM(ABS(yourRange))=0,"pass","fail")` - this is an array formula, you need to enter it by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
- `=IF(SUM(yourRange)=0,"pass","fail")` - all the other formulas work for all numbers, this works only if you expect only non-negative values in cells.